# Proof verification in group theory.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Here is a question that I am working on:

> If $G$ is a group such that *every* non-identity element has order $2$, show that $G$ is abelian (commutative).

**My attempt**

Suppose that for all $a \in G$, we have $$a^2 = Id$$

My goal is to show that $ab = ba$

Since $(ab)^2 = abab$ = Id, we multiply both left sides by $ba$ and we have

$(ba)abab = baId$

$\Rightarrow ba^2bab = ba$

$\Rightarrow bIdbab = ba$

$\Rightarrow b^2ab = ba$

$\Rightarrow Idab = ba$

$\Rightarrow ab = ba$

This condition will hold if I multiply $(ba)$ on the right side as well.

How does this look?

Comment: I don't see any issues here.

Comment: Looks good. An easy way to see this is to notice first that $a,b$ commute if and only if the commutator $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1$, and second that if $a^2=b^2=1$, then $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=abab$.

Comment: It's correct for me. Maybe you could slightly shorten it?

Comment: Yeah I am looking for a way to shorten this proof, if possible.

Comment: @Couchy311 Yes and in fact, I am actually going to be studying the concept of a commutator in class tomorrow, so this is a nice example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks good, well done!

A notional qualm: when doing these kinds of symbolic manipulation, using "$id$" to represent the identity can be confusing and hard to distinguish from other letters (plus causes confusion being the only two-character symbol). To me, the line $bIdbab=ba$ is hard to parse. $e$ is commonly used to represent the identity in these contexts.

Comment: Yeah my professor would always write out Id, but using $e$ shouldn't be much different at all!

Comment: I agree with this, my professors always used $e$, it is easier to read.

Comment: I will actually talk him into using $e$ because as Stella said, it can be hard to distinguish which variables we are working with.

Comment: @i8Σπ_821 In handwriting it's less problematic to use $id$ because you can easily adjust the kerning to keep the symbols "clearly together" in contrast to the symbols around them. Additionally, I've gotten into the habit of writing multicharacter symbols in cursive so that they 1) stand out and 2) are physically contiguous to help the reader keep track of them. This is actually something I've been doing since calculus, writing the $dx$ in cursive.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Yeah I can see why one would begin writing in cursive, especially when we talk about derivatives and calculus in general. Or any other subject, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good! To shorten the proof, I would write it like

$$(ab)^2 = e \implies ab = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1} = ba$$

Comment: or really just $ab = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1} = ba$

Comment: The important thing being that to have order $2$ is equivalent to being one's own inverse

Comment: I believe this goes for matrices too correct? Linear Algebra? The same concept can be talked about this subject as well.

Comment: I'll definitely keep that in mind Badam.

Comment: Sure, invertible matrices form a group under multiplication!

Comment: @i8Σπ_821 Indeed. Matrices have a group structure (actually two) on them and so all the same concepts apply. In fact, you can even have a slightly weaker notion than a group and have this go through.

Comment: This is what is amazing about math. Eventually, we will visualize how certain topics relate to other subjects as well and this isn't just limited to math only!

Comment: just wait til you get to category theory :)

Comment: I have no idea if I will ever cover that subject, but when I do, well just hope for the best :)